How to sort template column fluentui - blazor
I have the following:
 <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.UserName)" Sortable="true" Title="שם משתמש" Filtered="true" />

  <!-- UserName Column -->
  <TemplateColumn Title="UserName" Sortable="true">
    
      <CellTemplate Context="context">
          @if (context.IsEditing)
          {
              <input type="text" @bind="context.UserName" style="width: 100%;" />
          }
          else
          {
              @context.UserName
          }
      </CellTemplate>
  </TemplateColumn>

The first example would work.
However, when I have a more complex display of the grid, whether its in edit mode value compared to a causal display value.
The sortable = true is no longer useable.
It just wont work.
is there any simplified way to make it sortable without having to create buttons/events and so on?
